# Why credit card payment pages ask for expiration date?

Tags: e-commerce, payment

I can understand why credit card have an expiration date (reasons such as limiting frauds, the issuer being able to substitute the physical cards, and so on).

However, why all websites accepting payments ask the user to enter the expiration date?

Can the user enter a future date despite what is written in the card?

Shouldn't the payment gateway already know the expiration date given the card number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking the expiration date of the card is part of the process of verifying that the user is in possession of the card. Essentially, the month/year of the card's expiration become four "verification digits" in the card's number that one shouldn't be able to guess without seeing the card itself. One could think of it as a four-digit "password" assigned to the owner by the credit card company.

Expiration date has been part of verification scheme before e-commerce came along, when credit cards where used for placing phone orders. Once this level of protection has been deemed insufficient, credit cards added a CCV number to tighten the verification process even further.